# C++ How to iterate over template vector

Tags: c++

I have this vector:

```
std::vector<D*> _database;
```

typename `D` is representing this struct:

```
struct GameObjectsDatabaseContainer : GameDatabaseContainer
{
public:
    std::string name;
    std::string prefab;
};
```

And this function:

```
template<typename T, typename D>
std::vector<D *> GameDatabase<T, D>::GetDatabase() {
    return this->_database;
}
```

This is how I add data to the vector:

```
template<typename T,typename D>
void GameDatabase<T,D>::PopulateDatabase(D* gdc)
{
    _database.push_back(gdc);
}
```

And here is how I try to iterate over my template vector:

```
for(typename std::vector<D>::iterator iter = this->GetDatabase().begin(); iter != this->GetDatabase().end(); iter++)
{
    std::cout << (*iter)->name << std::endl;

}
```

Note that this iteration is happening in a child class which is passing `GameObjectsDatabaseContainer` as typename `D`

I am trying to reach `(*iter)->name` because inside `GameObjectsDatabaseContainer` I have a member `name`.

However this is not working. How can I iterate over template vector and display properly it's content ?

Comment: You forgot `*` after `D` in `typename std::vector<D>::iterator`. But you can replace all that with `auto`. Even then, the whole `for` loop can be replaced with a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) : `for(auto ptr : GetDatabase())`.

Comment: Beware that `std::vector<D *> GameDatabase<T, D>::GetDatabase()` will copy the whole `_database` vector each time it is called. Consider returning a `const` reference instead.

Comment: "This is not working" is not very helpful.  Is it not compiling?  Is it compiling but not executing properly?  How is it not working?   Please update your question with the exact text of the compiler error or a description of the nature of the problem

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux to make something like this you mean? https://pastebin.com/uDu4NtUb This however throws the following error: https://pastebin.com/AXgXVUV1

Comment: And even worse following what @FrançoisAndrieux said calling `GetDatabase().begin()` then `GetDatabase().end()` will create iterators to two different containers so your loop would also have undefined behavior after that

Comment: Using `for(auto *ptr : this->GetDatabase()) { std::cout << ptr->name << std::endl; }` will fix the issue that @CoryKramer mentions.